# element.class not applying styles to section

Tags: html, css

I have always done this if I want to ensure the class isn't used on anything else.

so for example `div.className` usually ties className to just div's. I have tried to do this with a section tag and the styles are ignored, can this not be done with section tags?

LESS

```
section.about {
    &__points {
      padding-bottom: 150px;
      li {
        padding: 10px 6% 10px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 46%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        text-align: right;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 0;
        margin-right: 1%;
        h2 {
          color: #fff;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          margin: 15px 0px;
        }
        &:after {
          content: '';
          background: #fff;
          position: absolute;
          height: 100%;
          width: 10%;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
        }
        &:before {
          content: attr(data-icon);
          font-family: FontAwesome;
          position: absolute;
          right: calc(~'7% - 20px');
          color: black;
          z-index: 4;
          font-size: 22px;
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          top: calc(~'50% - 15px');
        }
        &:nth-child(even) {
          text-align: left;
          margin-left: 1%;
          margin-right: 0;
          padding: 10px 10px 10px 6%;
          &:after {
            right: auto;
            left: 0;
          }
          &:before {
            right: 0;
            left: calc(~'7% - 20px');
          }
        }
        &:hover {
          background: #34373c;
          &:after { background: @accent-color; }
          &:before { color: #fff; }
        }
      }
    }
    &__bottom-image {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      img { max-width: 60%; }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="main-wrap">
      <section class="about">
        <h1>About <span>Us</span></h1>
        <p>Who are we at Mobile Paint Solutions, and what do we provide.</p>
        <p>Where did we come from, and where are we going?</p>

        <ul class="about__points">
          <li data-icon="&#xf007;">
            <h2>Who are we</h2>
            <p>Sed consectetur risus quis ligula dignissim ut pulvinar lacus. Vestibulum ullamcorper neque est, in tempus sapien eleifend quis.</p>
          </li>
          <li data-icon="&#xf0c2;">
            <h2>Future</h2>
            <p>Sed consectetur risus quis ligula dignissim ut pulvinar lacus. Vestibulum ullamcorper neque est, in tempus sapien eleifend quis.</p>
          </li>
          <li data-icon="&#xf05a;">
            <h2>What we do</h2>
            <p>Sed consectetur risus quis ligula dignissim ut pulvinar lacus. Vestibulum ullamcorper neque est, in tempus sapien eleifend quis.</p>
          </li>
          <li data-icon="&#xf1da;">
            <h2>History</h2>
            <p>Sed consectetur risus quis ligula dignissim ut pulvinar lacus. Vestibulum ullamcorper neque est, in tempus sapien eleifend quis.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="about__bottom-image">
          <img src="images/about-footer.png" alt="Mobile Paint Solutions" class="responsive-img">
        </div>
      </section>
</div>
```

Output CSS:

```
header #hdr-nav nav a:before,header:before{position:absolute;width:100%;left:0;content:''}.main-wrap section h1:after,.main-wrap section.about__points li:after,header #hdr-nav nav a:before,header:before{content:''}@large = ~"(min-width: 1366px)";@desktop = ~"(max-width: 1366px)";@tablet = ~"(max-width: 980px)";@mobile = ~"(max-width: 740px)";.responsive-img{max-width:100%;max-height:100%}article,aside,figure,footer,header,main,nav,section{display:block}@keyframes display{0%{display:block;opacity:0}100%{opacity:1}}@keyframes hide{0%{opacity:1}100%{opacity:0;display:none}}html{background:#1e2225;color:#fff}body{margin:0;font-family:Montserrat,sans-serif}header{height:100vh;background-image:url(../images/slide1.jpg);background-position:center center;background-size:cover;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center}header:before{background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);height:100%;top:0}header #hdr-logo{z-index:2;width:50vw}header #hdr-nav{background:#131416;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0}header #hdr-nav nav{width:60%;float:right}header #hdr-nav nav a{padding:15px;color:#fff;float:left;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;position:relative;margin:0 5px}header #hdr-nav nav a span{z-index:2;position:relative}header #hdr-nav nav a:before{z-index:1;height:2px;bottom:0;background:#cd1213;opacity:.3;transition:all .3s}header #hdr-nav nav a:hover:before{height:100%}#side-menu-icon{animation-name:hide;animation-duration:0s;animation-fill-mode:forwards;animation-iteration-count:1;position:fixed;top:20px;right:20px;border:2px solid #fff;border-radius:50px;width:50px;height:50px;z-index:999;transition:transform .5s;cursor:pointer}#side-menu-icon.sticky{display:block;animation-name:display;animation-duration:.5s;animation-fill-mode:forwards}#side-menu-icon.unsticky{animation-name:hide;animation-duration:.2s;animation-fill-mode:forwards}#side-menu-icon .bars{position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;bottom:auto;right:auto;transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);width:22px;height:2px;background-color:#fff}#side-menu-icon .bars:after,#side-menu-icon .bars:before{content:'';position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:inherit;transform:translateZ(0)}#side-menu-icon .bars:before{transition:transform .5s,width .5s,top .3s;transform:translateY(-6px);transform-origin:left top}#side-menu-icon .bars:after{transition:transform .5s,width .5s,top .3s;transform:translateY(6px);transform-origin:left bottom}#side-menu-icon:hover .bars:before{top:-2px}#side-menu-icon:hover .bars:after{top:2px}.main-wrap{text-align:center}.main-wrap section{margin:0 auto;position:relative;max-width:1120px;min-width:735px;clear:both;overflow:visible;height:100vh;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center}.main-wrap section h1{font-size:42px;font-weight:200;position:relative}.main-wrap section h1 span{font-weight:800}.main-wrap section h1:after{border-bottom:1px solid #cd1213;height:0;width:150px;position:absolute;bottom:-18px;left:calc(50% - 75px)}.main-wrap section p{margin:0;color:#a8a8a8;font-size:13px}.main-wrap section.about__points{padding-bottom:150px}.main-wrap section.about__points li{padding:10px 6% 10px 10px;box-sizing:border-box;width:46%;text-align:right;list-style-type:none;display:inline-block;float:left;position:relative;margin:10px 1% 10px 0}.main-wrap section.about__points li h2{color:#fff;text-transform:uppercase;margin:15px 0}.main-wrap section.about__points li:after{background:#fff;position:absolute;height:100%;width:10%;top:0;right:0}.main-wrap section.about__points li:before{content:attr(data-icon);font-family:FontAwesome;position:absolute;right:calc(7% - 20px);color:#000;z-index:4;font-size:22px;width:20px;height:20px;top:calc(50% - 15px)}.main-wrap section.about__points li:nth-child(even){text-align:left;margin-left:1%;margin-right:0;padding:10px 10px 10px 6%}.main-wrap section.about__points li:nth-child(even):after{right:auto;left:0}.main-wrap section.about__points li:nth-child(even):before{right:0;left:calc(7% - 20px)}.main-wrap section.about__points li:hover{background:#34373c}.main-wrap section.about__points li:hover:after{background:#cd1213}.main-wrap section.about__points li:hover:before{color:#fff}.main-wrap section.about__bottom-image{position:absolute;bottom:0}.main-wrap section.about__bottom-image img{max-width:60%}.main-wrap section.gallery__hero{position:absolute;top:0;left:0}body.nav-open #side-menu-icon{transform:rotate(180deg)}body.nav-open #side-menu-icon .bars{transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)}body.nav-open #side-menu-icon .bars:before{width:50%;transform:rotate(-45deg)}body.nav-open #side-menu-icon .bars:after{width:50%;transform:rotate(45deg)}body.nav-open #side-menu-icon:hover .bars:after,body.nav-open #side-menu-icon:hover .bars:before{top:0}
```

Comment: What value is in it `@accent-color` . Is scss compiled successfully?

Comment: yes, CSS's classes can be applied to any html element, including <section></section>, but your CSS looks like sass or less, did you compile it?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it's LESS, and it compiling yes.

Comment: Please post your final output CSS.

Comment: Posted, might need to use Ctrl + F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS compiles to ...

```
section.about__points{}
```

... which is not a section, it's an unordered list.

Change your LESS to ...

```
section.about{
    .about{
        &__points{
            // Continue/nest rules from here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, my mistake on the LESS code. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome - purely out of interest though: why do you prefer to overqualify your selectors? Are there instances of `.about__points` not in a `<section>`? It seems like you're already using a BEM(ish) pattern, why not opt for class names and a flat(ter) specificity?

Comment: To be honest this is the first time actually using BEM so i'm probably doing it wrong. So I will take that into consideration.